# Sakai 20.x Deploy failure in sakai-portal-api

Tags: maven, sakai

System:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Java version: 11.0.9.1
- Apache Maven 3.6.3
- Tomcat 9

deploy process stops after sakai-portal-api (without error text)

```
sudo mvn clean install sakai:deploy -Dmaven.tomcat.home=/usr/share/tomcat9 -Dsakai.home=/usr/share/tomcat9/sakai -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ sakai-portal-api ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 36 source files to /usr/share/tomcat9/sakai/portal/portal-api/api/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Sakai base pom 20-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Sakai Master ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.351 s]
```

```
[INFO] COMMONS ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.008 s]
[INFO] COMMONS API ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.253 s]
[INFO] sakai-portal base (neo) ............................ SUCCESS [  0.007 s]
[INFO] sakai-portal-api ................................... FAILURE [  0.341 s]
[INFO] sakai-portal-util .................................. SKIPPED
```

I've tested with maven option "*-Dmaven.test.skip=true*" too, but same error

I also tested with the stable version "*git checkout 20.0*" (instead of 20.x), but then it stops at "*Sakai Component Manager*"

Any idea, what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use java 8 because sakai 9 recommend it